# How to Access Azure Devops Artifact Feed from different Organization with out PAT token

Tags: azure-artifacts

How to Access Azure Devops Artifact Feed from different Organization with out PAT token.is there any other alternative to authenticate. because pat tokens will expire in due time.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you want to access it. In the security settings of an Azure Active Directory backed Azure Repos feed you can set the access type to "Anyone in my AAD".

[image: Members of your AAD]

You can also edit the feed-view settings to make the feed available to a whole org:

[image]